# How do I go about getting the Ajax Queue plugin working in jQuery 1.3?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an app that sends multiple Ajax requests simultaneously. I was originally running into race conditions until I discovered the [jQuery Ajax Queue plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxqueue), which works great with jQuery 1.2, but fails with jQuery 1.3. There are actually two different versions of the plugin; I am currently using [this one](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/ajaxQueue/jquery.ajaxQueue.js) which is the same as the first but just adds a bit more functionality.

Anyway, I am using Firebug on Firefox 3.0.10 and when I run my code I don't receive any explicit errors, the call is just never returned.

I could obviously continue using v1.2 but would really like to learn why this plugin fails with the latest release and what I can do to get it working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What failure messages are you getting?  Where are you checking for errors?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to use jQuery's built-in queue support if you're willing to do a bit of legwork.

```
// First Ajax request
$(document).queue("ajaxRequests", function() {
  $.ajax({
    // Stuff
    success: function() {
      $(document).dequeue("myName");
    });
  });
});

// Second Ajax request
$(document).queue("ajaxRequests", function() {
  $.ajax({
    // Stuff
    success: function() {
      $(document).dequeue("myName");
    });
  });
});

// Trigger the queue
$(document).dequeue("ajaxRequests");
```

Of course, it would be pretty easy to wrap that in a plugin.

Comment: I just discovered this answer via Google.  This worked amazing for my site.  Thanks!

Comment: Also a keeping a flag with the document element with data() helps when you want to keep track of requests made and when to queue the requests

Comment: why is the name passed to dequeue "myName" different from the value used in queuing them up "ajaxRequests"? Shouldn't they be the same (name of the queue)?

Comment: will that work? It will send the ajax requests one after the other, but they are asynchronous - they will both fired, rather than queued.

Answer (score 3):

Just found the answer to this looking for a solution myself. Someone decided to modify the original ajaxQueue plugin.

http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/10/11/ajaxqueue-and-jquery-1-3/

Answer (score 0):

[ajaxManager](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/) plugin is based on the Ajax Queue Plugin but is a bit more flexible and works with jQuery 1.3.2.