# Queue jQuery AJAX Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hey, I'm trying to grab a total amount of pages, and then grab the item_id's from each page. My code works but instead of each ajax request firing after the last one, they all run at once. How can I queue the calls so each call to get_page_items and then get_item is called 1 by 1.

```
function scraperFunction()
{
    $.get('./scraper/get_total_pages', { type: 'movie' }, function(data)
    {
        total_pages = data;
        total_items = total_pages * 6;

        for(page=1;page<=total_pages;page++)
        {
            $.get('./scraper/get_page_items', { type: 'movie', page: page }, function(json)
            {
                $.each(json, function(key, item_id)
                {
                    $.get('./scraper/get_item', { item_id: 'item_id' });
                });
            }, 'json');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Ajax Queue](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxqueue) plugin, or [use jQuery's built in queue support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881222/how-do-i-go-about-getting-the-ajax-queue-plugin-working-in-jquery-1-3/1062059#1062059).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `async: false` option in `$.ajax` request

```
$.ajax({
    url: './scraper/get_page_items',
    data: { type: 'movie', page: page },
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success. function(json){
       ....
    }
})
```

Comment: yes, UI is blocked until the end of the grab function... sometimes this is not a real problem...