# Abort previous AJAX call when a new one made?

Tags: ajax

I'm updating search results as the user types the search term.

When 2 ajax calls happen, sometimes the last one `data_response` is brought back first. I need to make sure this doesn't happen.

This is my code:

```
function filterCities(search) {
    $.ajax({type:'GET',url:'/ventas/theme/citiesContainer.php',data: "search=" + search,
    success:function(data_response){
        results.innerHTML = data_response;
        }});
    }
```

How do I cancell previous instances of the same request when I make a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution with a simple counter:

```
<script>
var counter = 0;
function filterCities(search,c) {
    $.ajax({type:'GET',url:'/results.php',data: "search=" + search,
    success:function(data_response){
        if(c == counter) { // Only update if it's data_response from last call
            results.innerHTML = data_response;
            }
        }});
    }
</script>

<input type="text" onkeyup="counter++; filterCities(this.value,counter);">
```

Answer (score 2):

You could transmit a counter in the URL, and send the counter back, and just ignore the results if they aren't from the most current iteration. Much like a sequence number in UDP packets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for an ajax queue plugin (or write one)

[How do I go about getting the Ajax Queue plugin working in jQuery 1.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881222/how-do-i-go-about-getting-the-ajax-queue-plugin-working-in-jquery-1-3)

just search some more here on SO and google for "jquery ajax queue"