# How to trigger ajax requests queue start?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, queue

I follow the approach given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1062059/604388) to create queue of ajax requests. But my queue is created online (depends on user actions), so I have function like below:

```
sendMessage = function(fieldName, oldValue, newValue) {
  $(document).queue("ajaxRequests", function() {
    // ...
    $.ajax({
      // ...
      success: function(data) {
        $(document).dequeue("ajaxRequests");
      }
    });
  });
  $(document).dequeue("ajaxRequests");
};
```

So, I'll call this `sendMessage` function several times. Since I have `$(document).dequeue("ajaxRequests");` at the end of this function, looks like it will not work properly - ajax will be started several times.

So, how to trigger function properly first time? Probably I should check queue length? Or, should I use [fully manual queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4785886/604388)?

Comment: I've abandon the que model for rapid concurrent requests.  Opting for a time stamp and unique client id allowing the server to sort out the actual updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the deferred object http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

You create a resolved deferred object acting as a queue and pipe your requests at will. For example

```
var mid=0; var queue=$.Deferred(); queue.resolve();

function sendMessage(msgId) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/echo/json/",
            data: {delay: 1},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(){
                console.log("Success for " + msgId+ "");
            }
        });
}

function queueMessage() {
    var m=++mid;
    console.log("Queueing "+m)

    queue=queue.pipe( function() {
        return sendMessage(m);
    });
}

queueMessage();
queueMessage();
```

A Fiddle to play with it http://jsfiddle.net/j6CKj/

Comment: Thanks, nikoshr. It doesn't answer my question, but this is good solution, so I am accepting it ;)